# Could prerender.io slow down page load?

Tags: angularjs, pagespeed, prerender

Just launched a site [bluesophy](http://bluesophy.com/) for which I am using a self-hosted instance to deliver HTML pages of my AngularJS app to google bots. Page speed insights from google are rather poor : respectively 33 and 27 / 100 for mobile and desktop. I know a couple of things I could do right now, but wanted to know if somehow using prerender.io could affect page speed load, or did someone face similar issue and how did they deal with it ?

Comment: Are you caching your prerendered pages on your self hosted instance? If you cache your pages, the response times will be < 100ms. If you aren't caching pages, then yes, your page load time would look slow since the prerender server would be rendering a new page every time a crawler requests it. Depending on how fast your website loads, that could take 6-10 seconds to render a page.

Comment: thanks @Prerender.io, and sorry for late reply. Right now our pages are indeed not cached. it renders every time google accesses page.  Looks like Caching will require additional software to be installed, for example reddis, memcahed ? do you have a standard solution you'd recommend ?

Comment: If you are using our hosted service, we cache pages for you so response times are around 100ms. If you run your own prerender server, there is very basic caching functionality included.

Comment: Yes we are running our own  prerender server. Thanks will look at the basic caching functionality